# Is it okay to use python mock for production?

Tags: python

A lot of my mock usage is in unit tests, but I am not sure if I can use the mock library for production, consider the following trivial example to get data from external source.

```
class Receiver(object):
    def get_data(self):
        return _call_api(...)
```

Now, can I use `mock` library to change the `get_data()` function for re-run purpose on production?

```
with patch('Receiver.get_data') as mock_get_data:
    mock_get_data.return_values = [1, 2]
    ...
```

Some might suggest to write another `Rerun` receiver as a better approach, while I don't disagree but I am still raising this question for the sake of curiosity.

My questions include:

1. If no, what's the reason?
2. If yes, any caveats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that for production use, a `Receiver` subclass that has an overridden `get_data` method would be much better.

The reason is simple -- if each type of receiver only receives data from a single source then your code will be much easier to read and maintain.  If the same `Reciever` will end up returning data from multiple sources, then the code will be confusing and you'll end up needing to hunt down whether you were fetching data from one place of whether it's data that you explicitly set via `mock`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If a function is supposed to behave a certain way in production, then *code it to behave that way*.  If you need fallback or retry behavior, mock is not the right way to do that.